# Unable to install Parrot OS in VM

Tags: virtualbox, system-installation

I keep getting this error when I install `Parrot OS` in `Virtual Box`.

> External command failed to finish.
> Command /usr/sbin/bootloader-config failed to finish in 600 seconds. There was no output from the command

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue when trying to install it using `.iso` file

I have successfully installed it using the `.ova` version (https://www.parrotsec.org/virtual/)

- Go to Parrot OS website
- Download
- `IoT And Cloud Appliances` button
- Select `OVA Home` or `OVA Security`

*Both HOME and SECURITY come with MATE Desktop environment*